# Hibernate group by returns own object

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, pojo

i try to resolve the own object in a hibernate criteria with a group projection.

```
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("personGlobal", personGlobal));

Projection projection = Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.groupProperty("organisation").as("organisation"))
  .add(Property.forName("id").max().as("person"))
  .add(Projections.min("activeFrom").as("activeFrom"))
  .add(Projections.max("activeTo").as("activeTo"));

crit.setProjection(projection);
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
```

i'd like to have something like this

Map of:

```
Organisation organisation;
Person person;
Date activeFrom;
Date activeTo;
```

I had in mind to use a kind of self join to get the person but didn't know how?
Some ideas how to get the person without doing an extra request? And without write SQL.